# Special Relativity time dilation measurement conditions

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

Let consider a frame (S) at rest and another (S') moving along (S) x axis with velocity v (typical example case for 1D + time scenario), with a clock in each frame origin. 
According to Special Relativity, the time measurement on the moving clock in (S') would differ by the one on the frame at rest due to the time dilation effect.
A delta time can be measured on each frame taking it in the worldline of the corresponding clock, i.e. assuming the clock not moving in space. Doing that, the comparison of the two delta times in (S) and in (S') shows the time dilation affect between the two frames.
That's the theory, but experimentally I've seen many cases where the measurements are taken using different start-stop space positions for the moving clock (e.g. Hafele-Keating experiment and also many others more recent using satellite data).
What am I missing?

Comment: I am sorry. Reading your post I cannot determine what your concern is. Can you clarify? Is there something that you don’t understand about the theory or about the experiments, and if so what?

Comment: Sorry for not to be clear. My point is that a proper or absolute delta time in a reference frame must be taken using a clock in the same spatial position in order to have an actual time measurement, but I've read about  several experiments where it is taken using moving clocks (e.g. Hafele-Keating experiment), and considering as source of the time delay actually the position difference as well. Those two points looks in contrast to each other. Which of the two is correct?

Comment: Good answers heavily depend on previous clear question. Try to rewrite the final part of your post making more clear: i) the difference you see between theory and experiments; ii) what is puzzling you. A look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask might help.

Comment: SR theory imposes to measure a delta time as difference of two space-time events e1 and e2 occurring along same position worldline, by applying the Minkowsky metric ds² = c² dt² - dx². Id dx = 0 then the event distance is the delta time.

Comment: But if I look at time dilation measurements for rotating clocks (e.g. Hafele-Keating experiment) the time dilation is calculated using Lorentz on events with different time (ok) and position (not-ok), e.g. considering an Earth clock rotation different from multiples of 360 deg (i.e. not getting back to the initial point).

Comment: Consider two clocks, one on the plane, and one in the lab. Now consider the two events, the plane taking off, and the plane returning. The time intervals between these events $\Delta t$ and $\Delta t^\prime$ are what we want to compare.

In $S$ (the lab frame), Event 1 has coordinates $(x_1, t_1)$ and Event 2 has coordinates $(x_1, t_2)$, since the plane comes back to the lab.

Similarly, in $S^\prime$, the plane-clock's frame, Event 1 has coordinates $(x_1^\prime, t_1^\prime)$ and Event 2 has coordinates $(x_1^\prime, t_2^\prime)$. Note that in both cases, $\Delta x=0=\Delta x^\prime$.

Comment: The notion of time difference in a frame does *not* require the measurement be made at the same spatial coordinates if a suitable synchronization scheme is in use. Einstein described such a scheme, and there are equivalent procedures if you find his clunky.

Comment: What Philip said. OTOH, the location of the plane taking off & landing is only the same in the reference frame where the Earth is at rest. It's a little more complicated if we want to take the Earth's rotation into account, not to mention its orbit around the Sun, the solar system's motion in the galaxy, etc.

Comment: @Gianni For some details on what dmckee said, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation and https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/Goodies/rel_of_sim/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the comments, I think you need to look at how an array of clocks can be synchronised so that the time in that frame is available everywhere.

The way you describe a moving clock as running slow is by comparing the time it shows with the different clocks it passes that you have synchronised in your frame.

The observer in the other frame sees one of your clocks running slow by comparing the time it shows with the time on his synchronised clocks as it passes them.

You then see why when you look at his array of clocks they do not appear to you to be synchronised, and yours will seem not to be synchronised to him.

Neither of you can talk about THE time in the other's frame.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies provided. More clear now. I'll go through clock sync for clarifying my doubts about this topic.